# Equivalence relations involving power sets

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I understand how to prove basic problems ($(X, Y ) \in R_1$ iff $X^2=Y^2$, for example) on equivalence relations but I have some difficulty solving equivalence relations involving sets and power sets.

Is P(S) the domain and codomain here for X, Y?

Any help would be appreciated.

Let $S$ be a set with at least two elements. Consider the following three relations on $\mathcal P(S)$.
Determine which of the properties - reflexivity, symmetry, antisymmetry, transitivity - each of relations possesses. Give a proof or counterexample as appropriate.

(a) $(X, Y ) \in R_1$ if and only if $X \subseteq Y$.

(b) $(X, Y ) \in R_2$ if and only if $X$ is strictly a subset of $Y$ ($X$ does not equal to $Y$).

(c) $(X, Y ) \in R_3$ if and only if $X \cap Y = \emptyset$.

Comment: The process of math is one of discovery. Can you check by hand which of the relations holds true for $S = \{a,b\}$. This should give you some pretty good guesses for all three parts

Comment: what do you mean by hold true for S={a,b} sir?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for (a):**

Let $X, Y, Z \in \mathcal P(S)$.

Reflexivity is satisfied, since obviously $X \subseteq X$

Symmetry is not satisfied. We know $S$ has at least two elements, so we can choose two distinct elements $a, b \in S$. Then $\{a\} \subseteq \{a,b\}$ but $\{a,b\} \not \subseteq \{a\}$.

Transitivity is satisfied: Let $X \subseteq Y \subseteq Z$. Now, if $X=\emptyset$, then $X \subseteq Z$. So let $X \neq \emptyset$ and let $x \in X$. Then $x$ is in $Y$ but since $Y \subseteq Z$, we also have $x \in Z$. That shows $X\subseteq Z$.

Can you do the rest now?

Comment: what does symmetry have to do with power set? a,b is elements of S  but does P(S) have to do with anything here? x,y should be elements of P(S) if I am correct?

Comment: @jamesFifa If $a,b \in S$ then, as brot puts it, $\{a\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ are elements of $\mathcal{P}(S)$.